# You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React, got this error:
[image: Error]

You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).

Here is my code:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {Header} from "./Header"
    import {HomePage} from "./HomePage"
    
    
    import { FontFamily, FontSize, gray2 } from './Styles';
    /** @jsxRuntime classic */
    /** @jsx jsx */
    import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/react';
    
    
    
    function App() {
    
      return (
          <div data-css={css`
            font-family: ${FontFamily};
            font-size: ${FontSize};
            color: ${gray2};
          `}>
          
          <Header/>
          <HomePage/>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Styles file:

```
export const gray1 = '#383737';
export const gray2 = '#5c5a5a';
export const gray3 = '#857c81';
export const gray4 = '#b9b9b9';
export const gray5 = '#e3e2e2';
export const gray6 = '#f7f8fa';
export const primary1 = '#681c41';
export const primary2 = '#824c67';
export const accent1 = '#dbb365';
export const accent2 = '#efd197';
export const FontFamily = "'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif";
export const FontSize = '26px';
```

Comment: what is the error? can you please attach the error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, attached.

Comment: could you show us the styles file